# Why dont i need http2MessageConverter in my dispatcher servlet

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I am writing a restful service returning objects in my controller my dispatcher looks like this

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

my controller looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{bookmarkId}")
    Bookmark readBookmark(@PathVariable String userId, @PathVariable Long bookmarkId) {
        this.validateUser(userId);
        return this.bookmarkRepository.findOne(bookmarkId);
    }
```

in my pom i have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

My question is how does it convert my object to json when i havent configured any Http2messageconverter , my understanding is http2messageconverter requires faster xml in my pom in other to convert objects to json , so why does it work without explicit configuration of my jsonconverter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in spring by default when u enable web mvc either by xml or by annotation spring pre enables some message converters as listed below  and you can as well provide library for another converter if needed pr prefered

```
ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter – converts byte arrays
StringHttpMessageConverter – converts Strings
ResourceHttpMessageConverter – converts org.springframework.core.io.Resource for any type of octet stream
SourceHttpMessageConverter – converts javax.xml.transform.Source
FormHttpMessageConverter – converts form data to/from a MultiValueMap<String, String>.
Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter – converts Java objects to/from XML (added only if JAXB2 is present on the classpath)
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter – converts JSON (added only if Jackson 2 is present on the classpath)
MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter – converts JSON (added only if Jackson is present on the classpath)
AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter – converts Atom feeds (added only if Rome is present on the classpath)
RssChannelHttpMessageConverter – converts RSS feeds (added only if Rome is present on the classpath)
```